# PyPDF2 and PyPDF4 fails to extract text from the PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

```
import PyPDF4 as p2 
pdffile = open("XXXX.pdf","rb")
pdfread=p2.PdfFileReader(pdffile)
print(pdfread.getNumPages())
pageinfo=pdfread.getPage(0)
print(pageinfo.extractText())
```

While running the above the 4th line of code successfully returns the correct value i.e no. of pages in the PDF, however, the 6th line (PDF extraction) gives a one page long blank data. I've tried using PyPDF2 and PyPDF4 and ran the code in both Python terminal and sublimetext and in both cases the I received blank page instead of actual text.

Comment: PDF is a tax return and is completely all text format. No images whatsoever.

Comment: Alternatively they might have added text in a form usually not extracted by text extractors. Thus indeed, the pdf is needed for analysis.

Comment: okay, but I was able to extract the whole text in powershell using itextsharp for the exact same PDF. Anyway, since it's tax returns I can't share the exact copies but I'll to find a generic tax return online.
https://www.webtel.in/Image/Form%20GSTR_3B_New.pdf this is the link for PDF.

Comment: *"but I was able to extract the whole text in powershell using itextsharp for the exact same PDF"* - ah, that's interesting information you should have provided in the original question text. Normal text extraction by itext indeed does nothing special, it merely traverses the page content and the form Xobjects drawn from there. Also it uses merely  **ToUnicode** or **Encoding** / ROS to map to Unicode, no special information from e.g. the embedded font file. That is something any text extractor should do.

Comment: If you are using python3 and above, maybe you can consider PDFMiner.six https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I just tested your *generic tax return online*. A first litmus test is to check what copy&paste from Adobe Reader shows: Also nothing intelligible! And if you analyze the PDF: The embedded fonts are addressed using Identity-H and Adobe-Identity-0, and they don't have ToUnicode maps. Also no other mapping to Unicode either. Thus, you don't need a text extractor for those documents, you need OCR software.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) instead of PyPDF2/PyPDF3/PyPDF4. You will need to [apply the migrations](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/migration-1-to-2.html).

pypdf has received a lot of updates in December 2022. Especially the text extraction.

To give you a minimal full [example for text extraction](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html):

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

for page in reader.pages:
    print(page.extract_text())
```